# How to get requestBody from ExceptionHandling ExceptionLogger in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```cs
string lsRequestBody = string.Empty;

using (var loStreamReader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)))
{
    lsRequestBody = loStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: How are you handling the exception now? Your code doesn't have any try catch blocks. Please post all relevant parts of the code.

Comment: @Thangadurai Any error occur in context file then automatically this class called. I have used ExceptionLogger like this :-  public class WebApiExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            string lsRequestBody = string.Empty;

            using (var loStreamReader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)))
            {
             //   loStreamReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                lsRequestBody = loStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }